# Rails 6/webpacker... how get background images to work BOTH in development and on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, background-image, asset-pipeline, webpacker

In a Rails 6 app, I have an image file in app/assets/images/bgs/abc.jpg

To attach that image to `body` background, how can I have a style declaration in a `style` tag in application.html.haml that works the **same** for **both** local development and when pushed to heroku?

Works in development, but not Heroku, due I suppose to asset handling differences:

```
#application.html.haml
%style
  body::after {
  content: "";
  background: url("/assets/bgs/abc.jpg");  ### WORKS DEVT ONLY ###
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  opacity: 0.12;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  z-index: -1;   
  }
```

I understand I should be using asset_path but none of these work in development:

```
background: asset_path("/bgs/abc.jpg");
background: asset_path("bgs/abc.jpg");
background: asset_url("/bgs/abc.jpg");
background: asset_url("bgs/abc.jpg");
```

There is a spectacular amount of inconsistent information out there, some cases saying use asset-url or asset-path, some cases saying asset_url or asset_path, and even some cases saying use url(~filename.jpg), some say use background: some say background-image.

Is there a simple way to use a background image with the exact same code working both on development and Heroku?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is for the style definition to be:

background: url( asset_path("bgs/abc.jpg") );

that works on both development and production.

Answer (score 1):

Rails on production mode will precompile assets so that all images on assets folder (and child folders) will be precompiled and saved as `image name-fingeprint` on public folder, for example: i have a image `assets/images/bgs/pragmatic_programmer.jpg`, then after run command `rake assets:precompile`, this image will become `/public/assets/bgs/pragmatic_programmer-9aa8a13ac97f205fe891bee7c42c6e711f997186d8975d5a4106ca2fe53ccc61.jpg`.

That the cause your app work on development mode but not on production mode since the images path changed, you can access new compiled images by `ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper#image_path` as below

```rb
#application.html.haml
%style
  body::after {
  content: "";
  background: url(= image_path("bgs/abc.jpg"));
  ...
}
```

you could test on development mode, just run `rake assets:precompile` before start server.